# What quantities are associated with the strong and weak forces?

Tags: forces, weak-interaction, strong-force

If mass is the quantity associated with gravitation, and charge is the quantity associated with the electromagnetic force, what quantities are associated with the strong and weak forces?

Comment: strong: Color charge

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction

Comment: "Weak isospin plays the same role in the weak interaction with W± as electric charge does in electromagnetism, and color charge in the strong interaction" -Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction